# How to display image with values [0, 1] with PIL

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

I have an RGB image that has pixel values [0,1]. How do I show this as a standard RGB image using PIL?

I have tried converting and showing the image using numpy as follows:

```
orig = np.array(255*norm_image)
orig = orig.astype(int)
orig = Image.fromarray(orig)
orig.show()
```

However I get an error on the third line:

```
TypeError: Cannot handle this data type
```

What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do this:

```
orig = orig.astype(int)
```

you make the `dtype` into `int64`, which you can check as follows:

```
print(orig.dtype)
```

That is not a supported data type under Pillow (see [here](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/concepts.html#concept-modes)), so you will need to choose a different type, such as `np.uint8` from the list of supported types I linked to.